# Is there any way to prevent making changes to a variable after some time?

Tags: swift

I want to initially keep modifying a variable till and point, after which I want to protect and preserve the value in the same variable, and prevent any more changes on it.

To do this, I know that in java, I can swap the value to a current variable into a temp variable, destroy the old one, and then re-initialize the old variable as a constant to store the value from temp.
Or use a condition loop to keep on checking for a flag.
But I am looking for a different solution

```swift
///I need something like this:

var manager = true
var version = 0.0 //initial value
while true {
  switch choice {
    case 1: version += 1.0  //changes permitted
    case 0: break
  }
  if manager == false {
    //something here to prevent any more changes to version variable
    break
  }
}

version += 1.0 // should not be possible now
```

After that process, the version variable must henceforth be immutable.

Comment: What about moving the code to a private func that returns a version number and then have `let version = someFunc()`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, a doubt: This means I'll have to use a different variable inside the function, right? (because I want to keep working on the _same_ variable `version`)
Please tell me if I am wrong...

Comment: Yes it will be a local variable that only exists in the scope of that function

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I guess if I don't mind change of scope, it is a good trick!
:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**swift 4.2 / Xcode 10.1:**

You can do pretty much everything using property observer (`willSet` / `didSet`).

**For Example:**

```
class Versions {

    var manager = true

    var version: Float {

        willSet(toNewVersion) {

            print("\nVersion will be set:")
            print("from current value: \(version)")
            print("to version value: \(toNewVersion).\n")

        }

        didSet(fromOldVersion) {

            print("Version was changed:")
            print("from current value: \(fromOldVersion)")
            print("to version value: \(version).\n")

            //use each one (if) you need.
            if version > 4.1 {
                print("Prevent Changes.")
                version = fromOldVersion
            }

            if manager == false {
                print("Prevent Changes(Got False).\n")
                version = fromOldVersion
            }
        }
    }

    init(version:Float) {
        self.version = version
    }
}
```

- `willSet` is called before the value is stored.
- `didSet` is called after the new value is stored.

**Some results:**

```
let app: Versions = Versions(version: 1.0)

app.version = 1.1
print("version number is \(app.version)") //version number is 1.1

app.version = 2.4
print("version number is \(app.version)") //version number is 2.4

app.version = 5.0
print("version number is \(app.version)") //version number is 2.4

app.manager = false

app.version = 3.5
print("version number is \(app.version)") /*version number is 2.4*/
```